# JQuery "Chosen" dropdown cut when appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I use JQuery "Chosen Dropdowns" plugin and have an issue that when dropdown appear inside
modal form it cut's and show's only partially, although parent div for chosen select has css property `overflow: visible`

[image]

Normally, when I use default select without any styling it works good

[image]

Maybe someone has same issue or can provide any solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="addNewLicense" style="overflow:visible;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Start date: </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="startLicenseDate" placeholder="Start Date..." style="width: 200px; height: 24px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>End date: </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="endLicenseDate" placeholder="End Date..." style="width: 200px; height: 24px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>State Name: </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="stateLicenseSelect" style="width: 205px; height: 30px;">

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
    $("#stateLicenseSelect").chosen({ width: "200px", disable_search: true });
    $(".addNewLicense").dialog('open');
```

Comment: edited, also selects content init's via separate Ajax-Request and then chosen select updates.

Comment: @Alex44 Can you provide your CSS too?

Comment: Plz, post link on working site

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery UI modals have overflow with hidden value by default, that to prevent any over sized object to leave the box boundaries. It won't crop the native UI controls from the browser because it would break user experience rules, but for script generated UI, it will. Chosen works replacing the select input elements with some absolute positioned elements that will be cut with overflow hidden.

To prevent this issue, you simply overwrite the overflow hidden property from jQuery UI:

```
.ui-dialog{
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I made a quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/e57gase7/

If you try removing the CSS in the example, it would look like your problem.

Comment: Because initial could have problem in browser support: it may be better to do: 
`.ui-dialog-content {
    overflow: visible;
}`

Comment: Oh, cool then @mikewasmike, problems exactly how? Not wanting to commit the same mistakes all over again if it mess up everything :)

Comment: @marcovega i don't quite remember which property it was, but I once found initial values for major browsers to be different, so it is better to be specific.

Comment: Thanks @mikewasmike, I have updated the answer so everyone is safe :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.mCSB_container {
overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Worked for me!!!

Comment: A bit more description would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your chosen with [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). It has more functionality, and should work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

This Code Worked for me:

```
   $(function () {
       $("#YourDropDownID").parent().css("overflow", "visible");
   })
```

This is useful when you do not know the class or id of the parent div/dialog